# In my sqlite table how to find the particular amount using phone number as a key?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I am using java and Android studio

```
final String SQL_CREATE_GROCERYLIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
            TABLE_NAME + " (" +

            COLUMN_PHONE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_ACCOUNT + "TEXT NOT NULL, "+
            COLUMN_IFSC + "TEXT NOT NULL"+
            ");";
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_GROCERYLIST_TABLE);
```

Answer (score 1):

this is a one way to get the amount column using phone number

```java
int phone_num = 05987555 // some phone number

// Filter results WHERE "phone" = phone_num 
String selection = COLUMN_PHONE + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { phone_num };

// Define a projection that specifies which columns from the database
// you will actually use after this query.
String[] projection = { COLUMN_PHONE };

Cursor cursor = db.query(
    TABLE_NAME,   // The table to query
    projection,             // The array of columns to return (pass null to get all)
    selection,              // The columns for the WHERE clause
    selectionArgs,          // The values for the WHERE clause
    null,                   // don't group the rows
    null,                   // don't filter by row groups
    null                    // don't sort order
    );

int amount;

if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    amount = cursor.getInt( COLUMN_PHONE );
} else {
    // If phone number doesn't exist
}

int some_int = amount*855 // do whatever with amount
```

for full documentation check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))